# Tabletools export buttons are duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

Edit** This question was about other problem i already solved. But now i'm with this new problem.

I'm trying to move the tabletools button outside the table, inside a custom div.
I already did it with the following code:

```
<div class="table-wrap">
    <div class="show-export"></div>
    <table id="" class="tab-display tab-search export">
        <thead> ...
        </thead>
        <tbody> ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

$('.tab-display').DataTable({
    dom: '<"bottom"i>rt<"bottom"lp>T<"clear">',
    fnInitComplete: function ( oSettings ) {
        var otb = $(".DTTT_container")
        $(".show-export").append(otb);
    }
});
```

But what happen is, the buttons are getting duplicated because i have multiple tables in one page.
If i only have a single table, it works fine, but not with multiple tables.

img with the problem: [image: link]

Also, if i give the following jquery code to show/hide the div, the buttons doesn't work.

```
$(".show-export").hide();
$(".bt-export").change(function(tablef) {
    var toShow = this.checked;
    $(this).closest(".wrap-export").find(".show-export")[toShow ? "show" : "hide"](500);
});
```

I know it's something to do with the fnResizeButtons.
But i only found solutions to use with tabs instead of hide/show jquery functions.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue so I settled for toggling the position of the buttons rather than showing and hiding.

Please note I am using DataTables 1.9.4.

```
// export controls
$(document).on('click', '.dt-controls', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.dataTables_wrapper').children('.DTTT_container').toggleClass('onscreen', 500);
});
```

**modified TableTools.css**

```
div.DTTT_container.onscreen {
    left: 0;
}

div.DTTT_container {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    left: 500px;
    height: 0;
    top: -39px;
}
```

Simply adjust the values to your liking.

For the duplicate buttons, do all tables have the `tab-display` class?

**Update**

According to [this](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3963/tabletools-on-multiple-tables), you need to use separate identifiers for multiple instances of table tools to work.

```
$("#table1").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>'
});

$(" #table2").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>'
});

$("#table3").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>'
});
```

So for your workaround you should only have these:

```
$('#table1').DataTable({
    dom: '<"bottom"i>rt<"bottom"lp>T<"clear">',
    fnInitComplete: function ( oSettings ) {
        var otb = $(".DTTT_container")
        $(".show-export").append(otb);
    }
});

$('#table2').DataTable({
    dom: '<"bottom"i>rt<"bottom"lp>T<"clear">',
    fnInitComplete: function ( oSettings ) {
        var otb = $(".DTTT_container")
        $(".show-export").append(otb);
    }
});


$('#table3').DataTable({
    dom: '<"bottom"i>rt<"bottom"lp>T<"clear">',
    fnInitComplete: function ( oSettings ) {
        var otb = $(".DTTT_container")
        $(".show-export").append(otb);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, i'm using a class because it's an admin template, so i'm using a lot of tables, and instead of using id it's better to use class. If i'ts only 1 table on the page, there is no problem, only when i have 2 or more. Also, i did what you said about the show/hide button, but the buttons still not work.

Comment: verify your DataTables button wrapper has the same class (`DTTT_container`) and also, use whatever class you have for the element toggling them instead of my own (`dt-controls`). I might have an answer for the multiple tools, I will update the answer.

Comment: The buttons i already made it work. It was some css without the relative position. About the duplicated buttons, i had already tried that solution, but i keep getting this error: "table id = table 1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable." Sorry, i'm new to jquery and plugins. =D

Comment: sounds like you have your existing code and then using the solution above whereas you need to combine your existing data tables initialisation that you have now with the workaround, I will update the answer based on the initialisation in your question.

Comment: It's even worse now.. http://i.imgur.com/v79Uhqk.png this is what is happening. I'm no longer using the $('.tab-display').datatables, instead i'm only using the code you sent me. If i use the [0] after append(otb) the amount of buttons is smaller, but still duplicating. But its more progressive, first table=4 buttons, 2 table = 16....

Comment: Oh, i made it work. But i don't know why... Basically i need to use append(otb[N]) where N is the amount of tables on the page -1 (start counting from 0). So i have 4 tables on the page and i'm using [3]. Now it's working. So if i want to use a single table, i use the class, and for the multiple table, i need to use special ID for each group of table. Thanks a lot for your time and your help!